# PHP Unicode str_replace Shows Up Blank

Tags: php, string, unicode

I am creating a simple webpage that translates between alphabets for a language I am making.

Here's how it works:

The PHP page checks to see if there is a roman letter 'x' and replaces it with the corresponding cyrillic letter for my language. It was working fine, but after I had completed adding all the letters, it stopped working. Now the output shows up blank.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
header('content-type: text/html;charset=utf8');
mb_language('uni');
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/font/stylesheet.css"/>
<title>Roman Corstek To Cyrillic Corstek</title>
</head>
<body style="font-family: 'dejavusans', sans-serif">
<h1>Roman Corstek To Cyrillic Corstek</h1>
<p>This webpage uses the font 'DejaVu Sans', unless your browser does not support web fonts (all modern web browsers do) because it renders Cyrillic Corstek Glyphs the best, and because it's free and doesn't come with a restrictive <a href="http://www.fontsquirrel.com/license/DejaVu-Sans">license</a>. If you would like to download a copy for yourself click <a href="http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/DejaVu-Sans">here</a>.</p>
<p>Enter your roman text below:</p>
<form action="cyrillic-roman.php">
<textarea cols="50" rows="10" name="roman">
</textarea>
<br/>
<input type="submit">
</form>
<?php
if($_GET['roman'] != "")
{
?>
<h2>Conversion:</h2>
<p><b>You entered:</b></p>
<p><?php echo $_GET['roman']; ?></p>
<p><b>Which in the Cyrillic Corstek Alphabet is:</b></p>
<p>
<?php
$output = $_GET['roman'];

//A With Macron
$output = str_replace("Ā", "Ă", $output);
$output = str_replace("ā", "ă", $output);

//B
$output = str_replace("B", "Б", $output);
$output = str_replace("b", "б", $output);

//V
$output = str_replace("V", "В", $output);
$output = str_replace("v", "в", $output);

//G
$output = str_replace("G", "Г", $output);
$output = str_replace("g", "г", $output);

//D
$output = str_replace("D", "Д", $output);
$output = str_replace("d", "д", $output);

//Œ
$output = str_replace("Œ", "Ё", $output);
$output = str_replace("œ", "ё", $output);

//Ž
$output = str_replace("Ž", "Ж", $output);
$output = str_replace("ž", "ж", $output);

//Í
$output = str_replace("Í", "И", $output);
$output = str_replace("í", "и", $output);

//J
$output = str_replace("J", "Й", $output);
$output = str_replace("j", "й", $output);

//K
$output = str_replace("K", "К", $output);
$output = str_replace("k", "к", $output);

//L
$output = str_replace("L", "Л", $output);
$output = str_replace("l", "л", $output);

//M
$output = str_replace("M", "М", $output);
$output = str_replace("m", "м", $output);

//N
$output = str_replace("N", "Н", $output);
$output = str_replace("n", "н", $output);

//Ó
$output = str_replace("Ó", "Ŏ", $output);
$output = str_replace("ó", "ŏ", $output);

//E
$output = str_replace("E", "Э", $output);
$output = str_replace("e", "э", $output);

//Ŋ
$output = str_replace("Ŋ", "Ң", $output);
$output = str_replace("ŋ", "ң", $output);

//Ñ
$output = str_replace("Ñ", "Н̆", $output);
$output = str_replace("ñ", "н̆", $output);

//P
$output = str_replace("P", "П", $output);
$output = str_replace("p", "п", $output);

//R
$output = str_replace("R", "Р", $output);
$output = str_replace("r", "р", $output);

//Ů
$output = str_replace("Ů", "У", $output);
$output = str_replace("ů", "у", $output);

//F
$output = str_replace("F", "Ф", $output);
$output = str_replace("f", "ф", $output);

//S
$output = str_replace("S", "Ц", $output);
$output = str_replace("s", "ц", $output);

//Č
$output = str_repalce("Č", "Ч", $output);
$output = str_replace("č", "ч", $output);

//Š
$output = str_replace("Š", "Ш", $output);
$output = str_replace("š", "ш", $output);

//H
$output = str_replace("H", "Һ", $output);
$output = str_replace("h", "һ", $output);

//Þ
$output = str_replace("Þ", "Ө", $output);
$output = str_replace("þ", "ө", $output);

//Q
$output = str_replace("Q", "Қ", $output);
$output = str_replace("q", "қ", $output);

//U
$output = str_replace("U", "Ұ", $output);
$output = str_replace("u", "ұ", $output);

//W
$output = str_replace("W", "Ю", $output);
$output = str_replace("w", "ю", $output);

//Ď
$output = str_replace("Ď", "Ь", $output);
$output = str_replace("ď", "ь", $output);

//Ť
$output = str_replace("Ť", "Ъ", $output);
$output = str_replace("ť", "ъ", $output);

//Ī
$output = str_replace("Ī", "V", $output);
$output = str_replace("ī", "v", $output);

//É
$output = str_replace("É", "Ѣ", $output);
$output = str_repalce("é", "ѣ", $output);

//Y
$output = str_replace("Y", "Е", $output);
$output = str_replace("y", "е", $output);

//Ğ
$output = str_replace("Ğ", "Җ", $output);
$output = str_repalce("ğ", "җ", $output);

//Z
$output = str_replace("Z", "З", $output);
$output = str_replace("z", "з", $output);





echo $output;
?>
<?php
}
?>\
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't know where you problem lies, but I would suggest just passing your search/replace values in arrays to `str_replace()` - that will eliminate the need to execute this function repeatedly. As far as your actual problem, have you done any attempts to debug to see where your value for `$output` varies from what you expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a function `str_repalce` instead of `str_replace` for the letter `Č`.

Just fix your typo and it'll work again.

---

To reduce your code size (`str_replace` also accepts arrays):

```
$output = str_replace(array("Ā", "ā", ...), array("Ă", "ă", ...), $output);
```

---

For the next time: write at the top of your php code:

```
ini_set("display_errors", "On");
error_reporting(-1);
```

This will help you finding your errors.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `str_replace` so many times, you can use [`strtr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) just once for all the characters.

```
$from = "ĀāBbVvGgDdŒœŽžÍíJjKkLlMmNnÓóEeŊŋPpRrŮůFfSsČčŠšHhÞþQqUuWwĎďŤťĪīÉéYyĞğZz";
$to = "ĂăБбВвГгДдЁёЖжИиЙйКкЛлМмНнŎŏЭэҢңПпРрУуФфЦцЧчШшҺһӨөҚқҰұЮюЬьЪъVvѢѣЕеҖҗЗз";
$text = strtr($text, $from, $to);
```

Comment: I think I'll use that when I develop my cyrillic -> roman converter.